# MVC - passing model from View to a custom helper

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to pass a model from a view to a helper, and get the following error on the @CustomHelpers.TopMenu(Model) statment: The best overloaded match for TopMenu has some invalid arguments. What am I doing wrong?

In my view:

```
@model List<ProductsStore.ViewModel.MenuItem>
@CustomHelpers.TopMenu(Model)
```

My helper:

```
@helper TopMenu(List<ProductsStore.ViewModel.MenuItem> menuItems)
{
    <div id="topMenu">
        <ul id="nav">
            @foreach (var item in menuItems)
            {
                <li><a href="@item.MenuHead"></a></li>
            }
        </ul>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: Where do you keep `TopMenu` is it in the same file ?

Comment: why don't u create the same foreach in the get action and pass to the view? can you show us the action you are using?

Comment: ::smack:: Turns out I had two @model statements in the cshtml, and the second, "wrong" one was being used. There were no error messages to indicate this. Just so this is not a total loss, there is a way to compile views, which would have picked this up like any other compiler error. Be aware that it does add considerably to the compile time. See http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/how-to-detect-errors-of-our-asp-net-mvc-views-on-compile-time-blow-up-in-my-face-theory